# Finding branch cut of special function

Tags: mathematical-physics, education, branch-cuts, branch-points

I am looking for the branch cut of this function
\begin{equation}
f(z) = \sqrt{3-\sin^2{z}}
\end{equation}
I have found the branch points of this equation as
\begin{equation}
z_{b1} = \frac{\pi}{2} + j\ \text{arcosh}{(\sqrt{3})} , \ z_{b2} = -\frac{\pi}{2} + j\ \text{arcosh}{(\sqrt{3})}
\end{equation}
From here it can be seen that $\text{arcosh}(\sqrt{3})$ gives us two possible values assuming $A$ and $-A$ ($A > 0$). Thus there are a total of 4 branch points for the original $f(z)$
\begin{equation}
z_{b11} = \frac{\pi}{2} + jA , \ z_{b12} = \frac{\pi}{2} - jA, \\
z_{b21} = -\frac{\pi}{2} + jA , \ z_{b22} = -\frac{\pi}{2} - jA,
\end{equation}
Until here I have no idea to derive the branch cut. If you get the answer or any idea, please share it with me. Thank you all!

Comment: $f$ has infinitely many branch points on the complex plane

Comment: @reuns I only consider the branch points which has the real part lie in the range $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$. Thus only 4 possible branch points are considered

Answer (score 1):

$g(z)=3-\sin^2 (z)$, let $a = arcsinh(\sqrt3)$,
the zeros of $g$ are simple at $Z=\pm i a + \pi \Bbb{Z}$

$f(z)=\sqrt{g(z)}$ is analytic everywhere except at the zeros of $g$ where it has some square root branch points (ie. $f(z)(z-c)^{-1/2}$ is analytic at $c$)

Let $U\subset \Bbb{C}$ open, there is a branch of $f$ analytic on $U$ iff for all closed curve $\gamma \subset U$, $\gamma$ encloses an even number of elements of $Z$.

Comment: I still don't figure out your idea about the branch cut. As you write $g(z)$ as above, I have solved the zeros of $g(z)$ and it gives us four branch points written in my equation as $z_{b11},z_{b12},z_{b21},z_{b22}$.

Comment: @TaQuangNgoc Is the last sentence clear to you, that each closed curve needs to enclose an even number of branch points? It is because when rotating (by analytic continuation) around a branch point $f$ is transformed into $-f$. It gives you many possible branch cuts, all they need is to satisfy this condition.